# How to make cross select in one table?

Tags: mysql, sql, select

Consider this table:

---

[image]

---

I need to make a SQL query which returns highlighted rows. In other words: rows which are linked to each other by idContactTo.

Example:
1 has contact to 2, 2 has contact to 1 - they are linked and should be in result table. But even 1 has contact to 3 it doesn't mean that 3 has contact to 1 -  they aren't linked.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it via `INNER JOIN`,

```
SELECT  a.*
FROM    tableName a
        INNER JOIN tableName b
            ON  a.idContantOwner = b.idContactTo AND
                b.idContantOwner = a.idContactTo
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/cc2fe/2)

Answer (score 1):

Another way to do it

```
SELECT t.* 
  FROM 
(
  SELECT MiN(id) min_id, MAX(id) max_id
    FROM Table1
   GROUP BY LEAST(idContactOwner, idContactTo),
            GREATEST(idContactOwner, idContactTo)
  HAVING COUNT(*) = 2
) q JOIN Table1 t 
   ON t.id IN(q.min_id, q.max_id)
```

Output:

```
| ID | IDCONTACTOWNER | IDCONTACTTO |
|----|----------------|-------------|
|  1 |              1 |           2 |
|  2 |              2 |           1 |
|  4 |              3 |           4 |
|  5 |              4 |           3 |
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e0f3e/1)** demo